# Extract value from specified row and column in CSV file using Python. Cannot use CSV module or pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been provided with a .csv file, which has data on covid19. It is in the form of:

```
district | country   |    date1      |      date2     |    date3     |etc
victoria | australia |1 case         | 3 cases        |7 cases       | etc
```

It is a fairly large file, with 263 rows of countries/districts, and 150 columns of dates.

The program needs to be able to take in an input `district`, `country`, and `date` and print out the number of COVID `cases` in that location as of that date. (print the value of a specified row and column of a CSV file)

We have been instructed not to use the CSV module or the pandas module. I am having trouble understanding where to start. I will add my attempted solutions to this question as I go along. Not looking for a complete solution,but any ideas that I could try would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Basically extract a value from a specified row and column in a CSV file, without using the CSV module or the pandas module.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a platform for providing code for your homework/assignments. Show what have you tried or where are you stuck and we will help in identify any bug or explain anything you didn't understand.

Comment: I understand that. I will add what I have tried to the question. Thanks for your interest. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: there is no much of ideas - you need to iterate over the file line by line and parse each line yourself.  look at `str.split()` method

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally did to solve it. It works perfectly. for reference the data file I am using is : https://portland-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/msharma8-c_ad_cityu_edu_hk/ES7eUlPURzxOqTmRLmcxVEMBtemkKQzLcKD6U6SlbX2-_Q?e=tc5aJF

```
# for the purpose of this answer I preset the country, province, and date
country = 'Australia'
province = 'New South Wales'
date = '3/10/2020'


with open('covid19.csv', 'r') as f:
    final_list = []
    list0 = f.readline().split(',')
    for line in f:
        if line.split(',')[0] == province:
            final_list = line.split(',')
    dict1 = dict(zip(list0,final_list))

print dict1[date]
```

I will use the same logic to finish the solution.

Comment: @buran Thank you very much for the string.split tip. That really helped me so much. Cheers!